# Get original message with headers when forwarding message before sending in EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, email-forwarding

I'm trying to provide a way to forward emails, just as we do in Outlook. When the user clicks forward, it opens a form with the original message and header information on top, giving the user an opportunity to modify the body. To get the message, I do the following.

```cs
    var item = (EmailMessage)dataGridEmail.SelectedItem;
    ResponseMessage forward = item.CreateForward();
    textBlockForward.Text = forward.Body;
```

I get an `ServiceObjectPropertyException` with message *"You must load or assign this property before you can read its value"*.  If I try to load the value of the body property before accessing, I get `NotSupportedException` with message *"Specified method is not supported"*. Is there a way to get the forwarding message before actually sending it?

Comment: You need to share how you are populating `dataGridEmail`, specifically the `FindItems()` call with the `ItemView` parameter.

Comment: `var exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);`  
`var itemView = new ItemView(100);` `listItems = exchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, itemView);` `PropertySet ps = new PropertySet();` `ps.Add(EmailMessageSchema.Attachments);` ... `ps.Add(EmailMessageSchema.Body);` `exchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(listItems, ps);` `dataGridEmail.ItemsSource = listItems;`

Comment: thanks for sharing the related source, please see response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `forward.Body`, you should use `item.Body` to populate your `textBlockForward` control. See [Forwarding Email Messages using EWS on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633681%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for more details.

```cs
var item = (EmailMessage)dataGridEmail.SelectedItem;
ResponseMessage forward = item.CreateForward();
textBlockForward.Text = item.Body; // needs to come from original message source
forward.BodyPrefix = "new body contents"; // prepended body content
```

Comment: In Outlook when you click on Reply or Forward, it shows you the **From**, **Sent**, **To**, **Cc**, **Subject** information, along with the original message. I guess I could add that information myself, but I was wondering if there was a way to get that from somewhere. I know that when I call the forward.Send method, EWS adds the header, original message plus the BodyPrefix in the Body, but I was wondering if there is a way to get that message before sending it so that the user can review it.

Comment: @stellkang - you would need to get those properties (*via an explicit `PropertySet`*) from the original message yourself. You could load them in your initial [`LoadPropertiesForItems()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.loadpropertiesforitems%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) or using [`Item.Bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635872%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for only the items requested to forward.

Comment: I was looking for an equivalent of RDOMail.Forward() in Redemption, which returns an RDOMail object with the body populated with the header information.  I guess it doesn't exist in EWS.  Thanks for your comments, though!

Comment: @stellkang - Glad to help you out! Please mark this answer correct if it solved your problem so that others may benefit.

Comment: Well, it didn't solve my problem, but I guess finding out that there is no such functionality is also an answer, so I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure if anyone could solve this. This is what i did.

```
    ResponseMessage responseMessage = message.createForward(); 
    // message is an EmailMessage object
    responseMessage.setBodyPrefix(body);
    responseMessage.save(WellKnownFolderName.Drafts);
    EmailMessage saved = responseMessage.save();
    saved.load(new 
    PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,ItemSchema.Body));
    MessageBody messageBody = saved.getBody();
    // do something with messageBody`enter code here`
    //System.out.println(saved.getBody().toString());
    saved.sendAndSaveCopy();
```